# Is it possible to use Selenium IDE html test and capture screenshots on failure

Tags: selenium, jenkins, ide, screenshot, capture

I have created a few HTML test suites with Selenium IDE. They are automatically tested and by Jenkins daily. Now, I'm wondering if it is possible to create a screenshot whenever a test fails.

Is it possbile to catch the exeption when the IDE test fails and capture the screen? Or is it only possible with TestNG? If it's only possible with TestNG, how does selenium HTML tests work combined with TestNG?

Kind regards,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Screenshots using Selenium IDE Firefox plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22300081/screenshots-using-selenium-ide-firefox-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

Selenium IDE doesn't directly support saving screen shots like this. Check out this other (duplicate) question: [Screenshots using Selenium IDE Firefox plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22300081/screenshots-using-selenium-ide-firefox-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

selenium ide does not have built in screenshot capabilities, but you can inject raw javascript: "javascript{alert();}" will display an alert. If you can find a way to do it in javascript, you could add the js to selenium ide.