# TakesScreenshot selenium html testcase

Tags: selenium

Is there a way that a html test could take screenshot?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
....
<body>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">texte1</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/Default.aspx</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=txt1</td>
    <td>test1</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>takeScreenshot</td>
</tr>
...
```

Comment: Looks like this was asked and answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22300081/screenshots-using-selenium-ide-firefox-plugin

Comment: tank you, need to be in firefox,

Comment: I think by default the selenium firefox driver has screenshots enabled, if not setup the capability.