# Screenshots using perl's WWW::Selenium module failing - anyone know why?

Tags: perl, selenium, screenshot

I'm just trying to test the screenshot functionality on win7 (32) using the snippet:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW::Selenium;

my $sel = WWW::Selenium->new( host => "localhost", 
                              port => 4444, 
                              browser => "*firefox", 
                              browser_url => "http://www.google.com",
                            );

$sel->start;
$sel->open("http://www.google.com");
$sel->capture_entire_page_screenshot("screenshot.png");
$sel->close;
```

Everything goes OK until it tries the capture at which point I get an error with message:

Error requesting http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/:
ERROR: Command execution failure. Please search the user group at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/selenium-users for error details from the log window.  The error message is: Component returned failure code: 0x80520001 (NS_ERROR_FILE_UNRECOGNIZED_PATH) [nsILocalFile.initWithPath]

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Although the docs don't say as much, a [quick](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/selenium-users/or0Gc-SP2RQ/discussion) [search](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22300081/176646) suggests that Selenium expects an absolute path, e.g. `C:\\screenshot.png` on Windows or `\\tmp\\screenshot.png` on Linux. It appears that Selenium requires double backslashes as a path separator, although you may have to experiment. Note that all directories in the path must already exist. (By the way, did you do what the error told you? There are several similar posts in the linked Google group.)

Comment: Re "It appears that Selenium requires double backslashes as a path separator," No, it expects a *single* backslash. The second one is required by the Perl string literals.

Comment: @ikegami The examples I found use Java, not Perl, but I think you're right: Java requires backslashes to be escaped in string literals.

Comment: Are you looking for an entire screenshot, rather than the browser window? If not, you should consider using https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::Remote::Driver which is newer technology

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone escaping the backslash has done the trick - also using:
$sel->capture_entire_page_screenshot('C:\Users\ELE03\Desktop\br_stack_sel_tests\screenshot.png');

Works - I think this may have been a perl thing - double-quoting I suspect makes perl interpolate the enclosed string and single quotes tells perl to treat it as a literal.

Comment: @RodAlexander Correct. Double quotes interpolate while single quotes do not, so you have to escape backslashes within double quotes.